# Problem connecting to a Minecraft LAN server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

I have a LAN server minecraft, but thanks to the UPS box with a buddy can not connect, and I do not know how IP: Port, permit so they can connect to my server. I Can not English, I am Czech. Translated in Google Translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LAN server is only meant for people on the same network. Port forwarding will not allow a friend to join if it is a LAN server, but a VPN program such as Hamachi will. 
To play with a buddy on a LAN server, he needs to either be on the same WiFi network as you or you both need to use a VPN. A program called Hamachi is used for this sort of thing all of the time. There are numerous tutorials on the internet for how to use Hamachi with your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at port forwarding. You have to open the port of your router. A possible simpler solution might be using VPN, which is more secure than port forwarding.